# XAMPP returns error "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: javascript, php, json, xampp

I'm trying to use XAMPP with the following snippets:

The php:

```
<?php
$api_endpoint = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast';
$api_key = 'my-api-key';
$url = $api_endpoint . '/' . $api_key . '/' . '37.8267,-122.423';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo json_encode($curl_response);
?>
```

The JSON itself looks like this:

```
{
latitude: 37.8267,
longitude: -122.423,
timezone: "America/Los_Angeles",
offset: -7,
currently: {
time: 1468248192,
summary: "Clear",
icon: "clear-day"
}
}
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myButton').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#myButton').fadeOut(300);
$.ajax({
  url: 'php/forecast.php',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data, status) {
      $('#content').html(data.latitude);
  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
});
});
});
```

I works perfectly on a live server, but when using XAMPP I keep getting the error *Unexpected end of JSON input*. Has anyone ran into this issue before with XAMPP? Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: If that's exactly what you got back, then it's not valid json. JSON **requires** all keys be quoted. e.g. `"timezone"`, not `timezone`

Comment: @Marc the JSON object was ok; in my post it lacked the quotemarks as I was copy-pasting some values from my browser where I use JSONview to view the object. As the response below found, the issue was my XAMPP needed the CA to handle a request to the SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine and the json format is okay (if your code works in a real web server there's no reason to think the json is wrong). First of all, you don't need to do `json_encode` because you know you'll get a json response from forecast.io server. And your ajax already contains `dataType: 'json'`.

The main problem here is that you are calling an endpoint provided over SSL (https://api.forecast.io), so your php server in your local XAMPP needs to use a CA (Certificate authority) to make sure the communication is valid.

Generally XAMPP does not give you this for free. So, download the latest CA pem file from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and save it in `C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem`; then edit `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and look for `curl.cainfo`, uncomment it and add `=C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem` to have `curl.cainfo = C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem`.

Save the file and restart your local Apache server. That's enough.

As a further note, to debug your php code, you may think to echo eventual errors. So add something like this in your php code:

```
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_error($curl)) {
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
echo ($curl_response);
```

and make sure you can catch the error string in your ajax.

Comment: Thanks @teo - that worked perfectly and it also explains why it was working on the live server, but not using XAMPP.